# Is there a good K++ Kode editor for Klingon?

Tags: unicode, editor

Ok, I know this is a strange question, but there is a "standard" (fan-wise at least) Unicode support for the Klingon alphabet, and since code can be written in Unicode with no problem, that means it is possible to write Kode with Klingon tokens( vars, function names, etc...).

For the record I've written C++ in Japanese and it works, so K++ in Klingon should work too. But I don't know of any text editor with support for Klingon. Any suggestions?

Comment: I was going to upvote this because you deserve rep for this, but I saw it was community wiki...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not likely, especially when you consider rule 9 of the [KLINGON GUIDE To Writing Perfect Code](http://www.aumha.org/a/klingon.php)

> “Indentation?! I will show you how to indent when I indent your skull!”

and number 7 does not bode well for any editor:

> “Klingon function calls do not have ‘parameters.’ They have ‘arguments’ . . . and they ALWAYS WIN THEM!”

`[`Seriously, this is an interesting [Unicode editor problem](http://www.oocities.org/harry_robinson_testing/klingon.htm)`]`

[image]

After all, ITunes has a license agreement in Klingon!

[image: ITune license]

And you need the right keyboard, off course \o/

[image: Keyboard Klingon i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01239/kling_1239147c.jpg]

Now... may be you can try to "Google it" ;-)

[image: KlingonGoogle]

Comment: I like this variant of the Klingon rules better: http://gradha.sdf-eu.org/textos/klingon_programmer.en.html

Answer (score 3):

> Number 1: “Our users will know fear
>   and cower before our software! Ship
>   it! Ship it and let them flee like the
>   dogs they are!”

Guess there's a lot more Klingon programmers out there than you'd think...

Answer (score 3):

Cherry has manufactured a Klingon keyboard:

http://www.cherrykeyboardsrus.co.uk/Klingon+Language-Details.htm

And, from the press release:

"Cherry has launched a Klingon language personal computer (PC) keyboard enabling users to use the Klingon language and fonts on their computers running either Windows, OS-X (Mac) or Linux. According to Chancellor Stalker Zantai Subaiesh of the Klingon Imperial Diplomatic Corps on Earth, "PC users will now be able to work directly in Klingon and interface seamlessly with commercial Klingon systems, bringing Human and Klingon cultures closer together."

Michael Groom, General Sales Manager at Cherry Electrical Products, comments: "The Klingon keyboard is the first step in providing PC input devices for all Federation cultures and will aid communications between Earth and other cultures within the Federation that fall outside the domain of Starfleet command. Of course, this keyboard demonstrates our capability to deliver custom keyboard designs, keycaps and layouts - whether on this planet or elsewhere in the universe!" Key features of the device, part of a broad range of Cherry keyboards, is its space saving, compact design, long-life and comfortable actuation. It is also recycling-friendly. The keyboards also deliver uniform switching characteristics and have abrasion-proof inscription of key caps.

Options include smartcard and/or fingerprint recognition support, long life versions with individual keys providing over 50 million operations, low-profile keyboards, integrated USB hub, touchpad, bar code decoder and inscribable keys, among others."

Comment: I *so* wish i had upvotes left, this would get one! does it come with obligatory "batleth" button?

Answer (score 0):

[important](http://ttp://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2134) obviously support: Klingon

> (to no use rejected by unicode 2000
>   in favor of comets,snowmen,4 scissors
>   and so) Comment 1 by gra...@gmail.com,
>   Sep 22, 2009 How can we use app engine
>   without Klingon support? :( Comment 2
>   , Today (27 minutes ago) recover the
>   Klingon fonts from imagefile will work
>   towards users, very sceptical it's ok 
>   engineering. signs have different
>   sizes. we could agree serve Klingon
>   with dynamic images. Comment 3 , Today
>   (18 minutes ago)

knowledgebase
http://std.dkuug.dk/jtc1/sc2/wg2/docs/n1643/n1643.htm
http://wazu.jp/gallery/Test_Klingon.html
http://www.evertype.com/standards/csur/klingon.html